# Recursive method call - determining output

Tags: java, recursion

This is question in the AP computer science.

```
public void doSomething(int value)
{
   if(0 < value && value < 10)
   {
      doSomething(value – 1);
      doSomething(value + 1);
      System.out.print(" " + value);
   }
}
```

> Which of the following will be printed as a result of the call doSomething(4)?
>   **A**. 4 3 2 1 5 6 7 8 9
>   **B**. 4 3 5 2 6 1 7 8 9
>   **C**. 9 8 7 6 5 1 2 3 4
>   **D**. 9 8 7 1 6 2 5 3 4
>   **E**. Nothing will be printed due to an infinite recursion

As I was working out the solution - it seems like infinite recursion to me E. Is that correct? What is the fastest way to arrive at a solution given that each multiple choice you get less than 2 minutes.
Any help in getting the fastest approach would help.

This question is supposed to be hand-traced. You cannot run the code to check the answer.

Comment: I can by writing the code and running it. But its supposed to be hand-traced.

Comment: Looking for the best/fastest approach for hand tracing the code.

Comment: It's easiest to check the corner cases first. You can see that doSomething(4) is going to call doSomething(1) fairly soon. Trace what doSomething(1) does by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Your question produces a `StackOverflow` due to infinite recursion. Next time you should try it for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that this is APCS exam question that supposed to be hand-traced. You cannot compile code and run it.

Answer (score 0):

It's infinite recursion because the value is always decreasing and increasing by 1.

Comment: It's only infinite if the initial call has `value` between 1 and 9 inclusive. Calling `doSomething(-2)` will print nothing and terminate immediately. Otherwise you're right.